# Mysql select count(*) from information_schema.columns

Tags: mysql

I've a table names users in mysql:

```
Create table users(
 user_id in not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username varchar(20) not null unique,
 password varchar(20) not null
);
```

when I execute

```
select count(*) from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'users';
```

It returns me `'12'`. I don't know why, it should be `3`.

Comment: To know why 12? execute this query: `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'users';`

Comment: Maybe there's another table 'users' in another schema? Try including the schema in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks   Grijesh Chauhan and abl, there's another table users in the other base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to limit the query by schema:

```
select count(*) 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'your_schema'
and table_name = 'users';
```

Or if you are already in the relevant schema you can use this as a shortcut:

```
select count(*) 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = database()
and table_name = 'users';
```